# $\sin(2\arcsin x) = x$

Tags: trigonometry

How do you solve for x in

$$\sin(2\arcsin x)=x$$

My first attempt was to apply arcsin to both sides, but for some reason I lose two solutions there. Why can't I apply $\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$ here?

Comment: `You can't because it is false in general. It is true only if $x\in\bigl[-\frac\pi 2,\frac\pi 2\bigr]$.

Comment: It is not generally true that $\arcsin(\sin x)=x.$ It’s only true for $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2].$

Comment: Hint: Supplementary angles have the same sine.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\sin(2\arcsin x)=2\sin(\arcsin x)\cos(\arcsin x)=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\sin\theta$. Then $\sin\theta=\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$.

So $\sin\theta=0$ or $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}.$

Then $x$ is $0,\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ or $-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.